# Which is better? mask_compress + store or mask_compressstoreu

Tags: simd, avx512

I am using sde (intel's emulator) to run avx512 code and do not have actual hardware to benchmark.

For some reason there is no information that I could find on comparative performance between compress + store and compressstore.

compress + store would store the whole register and not just the selected elements but I am fine with that. While compressstore has to mask the not selected elements.

What is better? There is no latency information on the intel's website as far as I can see.

Comment: Check https://uops.info/ for actual uops / ports / throughput.  Latency for stores isn't necessarily meaningful, unless something is actually going to reload right away.  Intel's intrinsics-guide latency / throughput are only a bit better than nothing when you care about throughput, since it's not like you can add up throughput costs if you don't know whether two instructions compete for the same port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPD: AMD - ZEN4. According to this: https://www.mersenneforum.org/showthread.php?p=614191 ZEN4 perf of compressstoreu is very poor, so if the code might be running on AMD -compressstoreu should be avoided.

I looked in a slightly wrong place: the compress instructions are only avaliable for epi32 and those have latencies:

`_mm256_mask_compress_epi32` has latency 6
`_mm256_mask_compressstoreu_epi32` has latency 11
and the others seem to require VBMI2, which are not available on my target.

So seems like `compress + store` should be better.

Comment: Mysticial's Zen4 measurement of 142 cycles for memory-destination `vpcompressd [mem]{k}, zmm` makes me wonder if that was a benchmarking error, like perhaps the upper elements needed fault suppression?  Or the mask was all-false so the page stayed "clean", and it kept suppressing an assist to update the page-table dirty bit or something.  Of course it is possible the microcode has a performance bug or missed optimization that makes it that slow even in the "good" case. :/

Comment: @PeterCordes I don't think it's a benchmarking error, I have a program which uses _mm512_mask_compressstoreu_epi8 and it was performing very poorly on Zen 4. I changed it to _mm512_maskz_compress_epi8 + _mm512_mask_storeu_epi8, computing the mask for the store using _mm_popcnt_u64 on the mask used for the compress operation and _bzhi_u64 on that, and the throughput increased by 15x. There is something wrong with _mm512_mask_compressstoreu_epi8 on Zen 4.

Comment: @JeffPlaisance: Yeah, https://uops.info/ has Zen 4 numbers now, too.  88 uops, 1 per 54 cycle throughput for `vpcompressd m256{k}, ymm`.  So it seems like a real effect.  It still makes no sense that it's so slow; `vmovdqu32 m256{k}, ymm` on Zen 4 performs great, 1/clock throughput single uop.  (But AVX2 masked stores are garbage, same as on earlier Zen CPUs.)  uops.info's testing of masked stores apparently forgot to initialize `k1`, so maybe it's special-cased for a mask of all-ones or all-zeros or something.